# Python 3 - "ImportError: No module named …"

Tags: windows-7, python-3.x, importerror

I'm getting an error `ImportError: No module named core.text`
I'm using 'ActivePython-3.2.2.3-win64-x64'
Actually, it was working fine in 32-bit win7. But recently, I have installed 64-bit win7. And now when I'm trying to run the same file again, it gives me an error. 
My directory structure:

```
my_SQLi.py
core
   text.py
```

So, I am clueless at this moment. Why it's throwing an error!!! Where and what changes I should make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a `__init__.py` file inside the `core` directory: this makes it a package, meaning you can access sub-modules with the "dotted" syntax `core.text`. The `__init__.py` file can be empty.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#packages